# Connection drop

Tags: configuration, switch, wireshark, bootp

Trying to solve this problem here but not 100% sure what's the issue.

4 Fetal monitors and a PC in a clinic are connected to a switch. Those communicate with the PC. 1 to 4 times a day there is a connection drop between PC and all 4 monitors. Drop lasts 10-15 minutes. PC responds to ping from outside the segment but monitors do not.

Looks like monitors are using BOOTP and have static IPs and are half-duplex.

It can't be cable issue because it's all 4 affected and it works most of the time. It can't be switch as it has been going for years and switches have changed.

How would you try to troubleshoot it from here on?

Was thinking maybe it's a software needing an update? It's kind of bizzare why would this be happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. please describe more the problem, as this line confuse me; "PC responds to ping from outside the segment but monitors do not."; The important point that you dont talk is; does the monitor ping from the PC in the same switch ? Did you tried a wireshark from the switch to see if the monitor *try* to answer something, as if it's silence radio on a monitor switch port, it mean you have a monitor problem. (firmware, etc..)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, all4 monitors do not respond when pinged from the PC which is connected to that same switch, nor they do when pinged from outside, but PC does respond when pinged from outside and all is normal. This PC has a software on it that interprets the data. I've made a suggestion to use wireshark to see if monitors try to communicate when the connection is down and awaiting results.

Comment: Yes, as all 4 drop connection mean to me something is broke for them. If you reboot the switch when the downtime happen, does the ping recover ? I ask as some switch got broadcast protection, and such can block those ports for X times.